# module template tag looping thru values in module template tag

Tags: templates, add-on-development

I am building a module and I am looping thru data to set a value for each key, to be used as EE template tags.

```
foreach($missing_fields as $field)
{
    $count++;

    $vars = array(
        'field_id'              =>  $field->m_field_id,
        'field_name'            =>  $field->m_field_name,
        'field_label'           =>  $field->m_field_label,
        'field_type'            =>  $field->m_field_type,
        'field_list_items'      =>  format_list_items($field->m_field_list_items),
        'count'                 =>  $count,
        'total_fields'          =>  count($missing_fields),
    );

    $out .= $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
}


return $out;
```

In the template, I want to display the field's label, which works, when it is a select field (notice conditional), I want to be able to loop thru the values.

```
{exp:module_name:form}

    <label>{field_label}</label>

    {if field_type == "select"}
    <select name="{field_name}"
        {field_list_items}
            {!-- loop thru each select value --}
            <option value="{select_item}">{select_item}</option>
        {/field_list_items}
    </select>
    {/if}

{/exp:module_name:form}
```

I created a format_list_items helper function that just returns a basic array of data for testing purposes.

```
return array('value 1', 'value 2');
```

I looked at the user module to see if they did anything like this in the profile edit functions & also looked at EE's myaccount.php line 364 (in edit_profile function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag pairs need to be formatted correctly as an array of arrays like this. Just think of the tag pair as a module tag, and the arrays as the `$vars` variable in your example above.

```
$field_list_items = array(
    array('select_item' => 'value 1'),
    array('select_item' => 'value 2'),
    ...
);
```